# Sharing a linux driver between multiple /dev files

Tags: linux, io, driver, port, tty

**Goal**: Take an existing driver controlling an FPGA that represents multiple com ports and separate each individual port into its own device file.

**What I need**: If anybody has some more thorough resources I can read to learn more about this, or has experience and can offer advice.

**What I have done so far**: I have looked for resources and found [this,](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN40) which seems to be a pretty thorough document for someone with limited experience writing kernel modules.

**Why I need to do this**: I currently have written software that uses my master driver to control all of the ports. I now need to allow multiple arbitrary programs to use some of the ports without knowing anything about my software.

What I have now is a single driver for an FPGA that I have programmed to have 16 full-duplex RS-422 ports that are controlled through my single driver. What I need to learn is if it is possible /how to create multiple /dev/faketty ports that can each call into my 'master' driver and control a single port while looking like a normal TTY port to any program that opens them.

Thanks for any advice.